# Install Matplotlib on Buildozer VM

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy, buildozer

I downloaded the Virtual Machine (for Android/Buildozer) from [here](https://kivy.org/#download).
I need to install Matplotlib on this virtual machine, but I am not able to. 
I already tried the following in the terminal:

- `sudo pip install matplotlib`
- `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib`
- `python -mpip install matplotlib`

I get the following error:

```
posixsybprocess.c:16:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-5xFopz/subprocess32/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-Q8TTao/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-5xFopz/subprocess32/
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev
then

sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install matplotlib

if it's not working:
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
or just
sudo apt-get install matplotlib

If it's not working at first try to upgrade and update the apt-get, then try one more time

Comment: sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-pip

Comment: sudo pip install matplotlib

Comment: Some problems with this web-site:(